# How to print milliseconds using format in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono, fmt

I have the following [code](https://godbolt.org/z/W7K8rK) were I am struggling to get the declarative way of doing what I want.

I would like to have current time outputed up to ms precission(rounding down is also fine, e.g 129999 us can be rounded to 129ms, but I prefer 130 in this case).

note: I am using fmt since from what I see `<format>` header is still unimplemented.

```
#include<string>
#include<chrono>
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<fmt/format.h>
#include<fmt/chrono.h>

using namespace std::chrono;
int main(){
    for (int i =0; i<5;++i){
    // I wish this was local_time, not sys time, and that sys_time<milliseconds> worked
    const std::chrono::sys_time<nanoseconds> now =
        (std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    auto round_now = std::chrono::round<milliseconds>(now);
    int64_t ms = (round_now.time_since_epoch()%seconds(1)).count();
    // %S does not print milliseconds
    std::cout << fmt::format("{:%F %H:%M:%S}.{:03}", now, ms) << std::endl;     
    std::cout << std::endl;   
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(100));
    }
    std::cout << "Bye";
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you presented? Doesn't it print the milliseconds?

Comment: Could you show an example of the output you get, and the output you want?

Comment: like I said I want a declarative way of doing this, instead of me manually computing the ms part of second.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <fmt/chrono.h>

auto a = system_clock::now();
print("{:%FT%T%Oz}\n", a);
print("{0:%FT%H:%M:}{1:%S}{0:%Oz}\n", a,a.time_since_epoch());
```

prints

```
2021-04-13T21:38:04+0800
2021-04-13T21:38:04.076+0800
```

Answer (score 3):

`%S` prints milliseconds by default. For example:

```cpp
#include <fmt/chrono.h>

int main() {
  fmt::print("{:%S}", std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
}
```

prints (the actual output depends on the current time of course):

```
34.459
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Y1jzv5

Comment: Interesting that `%T` doesn't actually mean `%H:%M:%S` though, that one prints in [seconds](https://godbolt.org/z/cPM6n4)?

Comment: Not sure that this answer is correct, see this:
https://godbolt.org/z/fKsz6e

Comment: Maybe problem is that I am using std::chrono::sys_time ?

Comment: sys_time formatting is a recent contribution and it may be incomplete.

Comment: @vitaut so to recap: story is that compliant C++ 20 <format> should print milliseconds when using %S, but fmt trunk does not(atm).

Comment: Probably. {fmt} should do whatever the standard says about chrono format.