# Timestamp Discrepancy Between C++ REST Client and JavaScript REST Server on Same Machine

Tags: javascript, c++, windows, google-chrome, time

I have a C++ REST client and a REST server running in Chrome as a JavaScript code. Both the client and server are running on the same Windows machine. However, I'm encountering a strange issue where the request received time on the server is earlier than the request sent time from the client.

Here's a snippet of my server-side JavaScript code:

```
const recievedTime = performance.now();
        const timestamp = new Date(
            performance.timeOrigin + recievedTime
        ).toISOString();
```

And here's a snippet of my client-side C++ code:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

std::string formatTimestamp(const boost::posix_time::ptime& time) {
    // Format the timestamp string
    return boost::posix_time::to_iso_extended_string(time) + "Z";
}
```

I'm expecting the server to receive the request with a timestamp that matches or is later than the timestamp generated on the client. However, I'm observing that the server's received time is earlier.
Client sent time : 2024-03-12T09:38:03.404Z
Server receive time : 2024-03-12T09:38:03.398Z

Could someone help me understand why this discrepancy might be happening? Is there an issue with how I'm generating or handling timestamps in either the C++ client or JavaScript server code?

Comment: Using MSVC and C++20 you can shorten your client-side to this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qKEd6EPqa

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but are you issuing the request on the client side before or after querying the clock?  Is it possible the server is receiving the request before the client gets a chance to look at the clock?  Do you have the same issue if, on the client, you query the clock before sending the request?

Comment: There is no snippet indicating the time order between sending/receiving requests so we cannot answer it.

Comment: Btw https://stackoverflow.com/q/63829143/4123703 should save you tons of formatting work . If you don't use C++20, go with libfmt.

Comment: In c++, the is measured just before send and in web, time is measures on receive message

Comment: Possibly related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78166839/mismatch-in-chrome-time