# Mismatch in chrome time

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, time

I have a publisher JS webapp, that publishes message with time. Time calculated using `Date()`. Another JS consumer app, records the received time.

Both the publisher and receiver runs **on the same compute**r. It is observed that time at the receiver's side is *earlier* than the sender's. (~6 millisecond earlier).

Received time is earlier than sending time. Expected result is

```
Received time = SendTime + NetworkDelay.
```

But the *actual* observed result is

```
Received time = SendTime - X
```

Is there any mistake in time logging code give below?

publisher code

```
const MSG_INTERVAL = 50;

function startApp() {
    const websocketUrl = "ws://localhost:9090";
    const socket = new WebSocket(websocketUrl);

    // Handle connection open event
    socket.onopen = function (event) {
        console.log("Connection established!");

        let timerId = setInterval(() => {
            const recievedTime = performance.now();
            const timestamp = new Date(
                performance.timeOrigin + recievedTime
            ).toISOString();
            const msg = `Send Message : ${timestamp}`;
            ws.send(msg);
            console.log("Send Message:", timestamp);
        }, MSG_INTERVAL);
    };

    // Handle connection close event
    socket.onclose = function (event) {
        console.log("Connection closed.");
    };
}

// Handle on load app
window.onload = startApp;
```

Receiver code

```
function startApp() {
    const websocketUrl = "ws://localhost:9090";
    const socket = new WebSocket(websocketUrl);

    // Handle connection open event
    socket.onopen = function (event) {
        console.log("Connection established!");
    };

    // Handle incoming messages from the server
    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log("Received message from server:", event.data);

        const recievedTime = performance.now();
        const now = new Date();

        const timestamp = new Date(
            performance.timeOrigin + recievedTime
        ).toISOString();

        const dateTimeStamp = now.toISOString();

        console.log("Performance TimeStamp:", timestamp);
        console.log("Date TimeStamp:", dateTimeStamp);

    };

    // Handle connection close event
    socket.onclose = function (event) {
        console.log("Connection closed.");
    };
}

// Handle on load app
window.onload = startApp;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78147688/1427878, which was asked two days ago, appears to be dealing with a very similar issue. Could perhaps indicate a bug introduced in a recent Chrome version?